# Should SimpleDateFormat with German Locale be able to parse a String with Timezone CEST?

Tags: java, timezone, locale, simpledateformat, ibm-jre

I have a Java application which basically contains the following code in a test and expects it to throw an Exception:

```
String date = "Fr August 21 16:41:32 CEST 2015";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.GERMANY);
dateFormat.parse(date);
```

While the application ran under Suns Java 1.7 it always failed, as expected, with this Exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fr August 21 16:41:32 CEST 2015"
```

It failed because CEST wasn't a legit time zone with German Locale. When I now run the same test under IBMs Java 1.8, it now successfully parses to

```
Fr August 21 16:41:32 MESZ 2015
```

So I wonder which behaviour is the correct one? Do I now have a bug or did I have one before? Or did I somehow miss-configure something?

Comment: Interesting question with no clear-cut answer, I’m afraid. Java gets its locale data — what the day abreviations and time zone names are in different languages — from up to four sources, and not the same sources in all Java versions. It’s a long time since I’ve worked with IBM Java, but I would think the behaviour is as IBM intended.

Comment: FWIW on my Java 10.0.2 too I get `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fr August 21 16:41:32 CEST 2015"`.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Will be curious whether it solves your problem, though, since it still uses Java’s changing locale data.

Comment: Is your default locale `Locale.GERMANY` too?